# Show option as selected in each loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am rendering all the option of the select box through an ajax call inside `$(document).ready()` function.

I have a PHP variable at the top of the page which is initialized with 1 like

```
$expert_id  = 1;
```

Now here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('insoadmin/experts/all_experts');?>",
            dataType: "json",            
            success: function(data, page) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    //console.log(data[i].expert_name);
                    $('#expert').append($('<option>', { 
                        value: data[i].expert_id,
                        text : data[i].expert_name,
                    }));
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

While appending all the option to my expert select box I want to check if `data[i].expert_id` is equal to my php variable or not, if it is equal to my PHP variable then it should be selected.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `selected` property/attribute while creating `jQuery` object(`<option>`)

Refer [**`jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)

```js
var data = [{
  expert_id: 1,
  expert_name: 'rayon'
}, {
  expert_id: 2,
  expert_name: 'bye'
}];
var expert_id = 2;
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  $('#expert').append($('<option>', {
    value: data[i].expert_id,
    text: data[i].expert_name,
    selected: expert_id === data[i].expert_id
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="expert"></select>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/mxhnpjp3/)

Comment: selected: expert_id === data[i].expert_id : i want this logic with the PHP variable

Comment: @PunitGajjar – You can have a JavaScript variable holding `PHP-value`, ex. `var expert_id = <?php $expert_id; ?>`

Comment: Thanks mate, it works like charm,  you have made my day . . .  Thank you so much

Comment: @PunitGajjar – Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('insoadmin/experts/all_experts');?>",
            dataType: "json",            
            success: function(data, page) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    //console.log(data[i].expert_name);

                    $('#expert').append($('<option>', { 
                        value: data[i].expert_id,
                        text : data[i].expert_name,
                    }));
                });

                var expert_id = '<?php echo $expert_id ; ?>';
                $('#expert').val(expert_id); //setting the value of select box
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: yeah this can be the way , but i would like to check it within loop  appreciate your answer

Comment: its a one time activity. So its better to do it once all the option gets appended. Checking the value within loop will obviously will add few mill seconds.

Comment: This was just an example , actually i have dynamic select boxes

Answer (score 0):

Define at top:

```
<span id="foo"><?php echo $expert_id; ?></span>
```

Add in the script

```
<script>


 $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url('insoadmin/experts/all_experts');?>",
                dataType: "json",            
                success: function(data, page) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        //console.log(data[i].expert_name);
                        $('#expert').append($('<option>', { 
                            value: data[i].expert_id,
                            text : data[i].expert_name,
              var foo=$('#foo').html();
              if(foo==data[i].expert_id){
          //do something
           }
                        }));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```